# Problem with deb installation alien converter

Tags: dpkg, rpm, jupiter, alien

I tried to install unsupported jupiter on Ubuntu 14.04, I got the jupiter-0.1.7-1.noarch.rpm from sourceforge and converted to deb with:

```
sudo alien -k jupiter-0.1.7-1.noarch.rpm
```

then alien generated jupiter_0.1.7-1_all.deb then I tried this

```
sudo dpkg -i jupiter_0.1.7-1_all.deb
```

so then dpkg throws this error

```
(Leyendo la base de datos ... 171516 archivos o directorios instalados actualmente.)
Preparing to unpack jupiter_0.1.7-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking jupiter (0.1.7-1) over (0.1.7-1) ...
Configurando jupiter (0.1.7-1) ...
chown: grupo inválido: «:jupiter»
dpkg: error al procesar el paquete jupiter (--install):
 el subproceso instalado el script post-installation devolvió el código de salida de error 1
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1) ...
Se encontraron errores al procesar:
jupiter
```

Then I googled and I read that alien generates this file when converts the rpm packages iinto deb

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info/jupiter.postinst
```

and this file contain:

```
#!/bin/sh
# alien added permissions fixup code
chown ':jupiter' '/var/jupiter'
```

I have only one user and is not jupiter so can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add the jupiter group to your system.  You can do that by running `sudo groupadd jupiter` in the terminal.  After that you should be able to install the package like you are with `dpkg`.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to use Jupiter on 14.04, try the following with your own risk.

1.Download deb files from [Packages in “Jupiter” “WebUpd8” team](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/jupiter/+packages?field.name_filter=&field.status_filter=&field.series_filter=)

```
jupiter_0.1.9-2~webupd8~0_all.deb
pyjupiter_0.1.9-2~webupd8~0_all.deb
jupiter-support-eee_0.0.13-1~webupd8~1_all.deb
```

2.Execute in terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install acpi libappindicator1 libindicator7 python-appindicator
sudo dpkg -i jupiter_0.1.9-2~webupd8~0_all.deb pyjupiter_0.1.9-2~webupd8~0_all.deb jupiter-support-eee_0.0.13-1~webupd8~1_all.deb
```

Note:'acpi' and 'jupiter-support-eee...' are option for EeePC.

3. Reboot PC

   sudo reboot